# Attaching TapGesture Recognizer to UIButton

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, uibutton, gesture

In my application, a UI Button is implemented for 'long press' event using 'Touch Down' and 'Touch Up Inside' events.

The idea is, as long as the button is pressed and hold, a specific action to be executed. When the button is released, then the 'action' needs to be stopped after one second of delay. The action is based on multiple threads.

Now the problem is, the UIButton is suppose to be operated as 'Long Press' and Release only. But, when the button tapped continuously, then the 'action' is getting crashed, due to the multiple calls of threads with time delay.

I tried giving 'UITapGestureRecognizer' for the entire view. But it doesn't work out.

Could you please guide me handling the UIButton being tapped to be ignored. That is the 'action' should be in stopped state only.

Comment: If you want to do something on long-press than do it with UILongPressGestureRecognizer. Why are you using button events 'Touch Down' and 'Touch Up Inside' ?

Comment: LongPress event 'initiates' the action. But I need to 'stop' the action when the button is released. Hence I used the 'touchup inside' and 'touch down' events.